# Regular Expression .net flavor

Tags: asp.net, regex, special-characters

Dont ask how this works but currently it does `("^\|*(.*?)\|*$")` ... kinda. This removes all extra pipes, part one, I have searched all over no anwser yet. I am using VB2011 beta, asp web form, vb coding though!

I want to capture the special character pipe `(|)` which is used to separate words i.e. `car|truck|van|cycle`.

The problem is that users often lead with, trail with, use multiple, and use spaces before and after each pipe i.e. `|||car||truck | van || cycle`.

Another example: `george bush|micheal jordon|bill gates|steve jobs` <-- this would be correct but when I do remove space it takes the correct spaces out.

So I want to get rid of any white space leading, trailing, any space before `|` and space after `|` and only allow one pipe `(|)` in between alphanumeric characters of course.

Comment: Can you post your code? It will be easier to understand what you are trying to do if we can read the source.

Comment: Why do you need to use regular expression. Can't you use Split method. Dim charSeparators() As Char = {"|"c} then 
 yourString.Split(charSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

Answer (score 1):

### Requirements:

- Remove any leading or trailing pipes
- "Trim" whitespace around inner terms
- Remove "multiple pipes at one time"

And these are some sample inputs -> outputs:

```
"|||car | boat|||" -> "car|boat"
"george bush|micheal jordon|bill gates|steve jobs"
        -> "george bush|micheal jordon|bill gates|steve jobs"
"     george bush|micheal jordon  |bill gates |steve jobs      " 
        -> "george bush|micheal jordon|bill gates|steve jobs"
"123|||123" -> "123|123"
```

And your example that *almost* works for you:

```
("^\|*(.*?)\|*$")
```

Before we go any further, it's a good idea to mention this MSDN reference page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx

And this online test page: http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

My regex-fu is not strong enough, because I thought that this regex might work, but it looks like a tough job. I documented inline, but it's still complex (and it completely doesn't work)

```
^(?:\|*)((?:\s*)([a-zA-Z0-9]?[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*[a-zA-Z0-9]?)(?:\s*)\|?(?:\|*))(?:\|*)$

^                                     - start the line/input
(?:\|*)                               - capture any pipes at the beginning but ignore them
(                                     - begin matching so we can get the values out the other side
(?:\s*)                               - trim leading spaces
[a-zA-Z0-9]?[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*[a-zA-Z0-9]? - match any alphanumerics with spaces in between
(?:\s*)                               - trim trailing spaces
\|                                    - match any one pipe
(?:\|*)                               - ignore any remaining pipes in a row
)*                                    - end matching, we should be done
(?:\|*)                               - capture any pipes at the end but ignore them
$                                     - end of the line/input
```

So, let's try and solve the problem, shall we?

You should split on pipes, look ahead and see if the next one is a empty length string and if not add it to the existing length of words. Let's try that:

(I'm going to use DotNetPad for this part) http://dotnetpad.net/ViewPaste/4bpRXD-vZEOwqTLDQbEECg

Here's a sample app that does what you need, with a minimum of fuss:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

public class DotNetPad {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        string[] tests = new[] {
            "|||car | boat|||",
            "george bush|micheal jordon|bill gates|steve jobs",
            "     george bush|micheal jordon  |bill gates |steve jobs      ",
            "123|||123"
        };

        foreach(var s in tests)
        Console.WriteLine(CleanString(s));
    }
    public static string CleanString(string input) {
        string result = string.Empty;

        string[] split = input.Split(new[] {
            '|'
        });

        foreach(var s in split) {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) {
                result += "|" + s.Trim();
            }
        }
        return result.Substring(1);
    }
}
```

I spent at most 10 minutes on the second code, and everything since I edited the post trying to get the regex to work. The moral of the story: only do the work you have to, you don't have to use a regex for everything.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by deleting the space :

```
MyString = Regex.Replace(MyString, "[ ]*\|[ ]*", "|")
```

then the multiple pipes :

```
MyString = Regex.Replace(MyString, "\|{2,}", "|")
```

For example

```
Dim MyString As String = "car  | truck ers  ||van|||cycle"
```

gives

```
 "car|truck ers|van|cycle"
```

Comment: Yeah, I was going to suggest multiple repeating regexes if he still wanted to use regexes. However, I think the array split and join is faster, if only because it's simpler to parse, because if he's going to go so far as to use regexes, he could just use string.replace natively on the strings encountered. (once for pipes, twice for spaces around pipes)